# How to replace gql type of query with Query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code, which works well:

```
comments = PersonComment.gql('WHERE ANCESTOR IS :parent AND verified=True ORDER BY added DESC', parent=person_key).fetch(PAGE_SIZE_COMMENTS+1, (page)*PAGE_SIZE_COMMENTS)
```

I want to replace that with:

```
  comments = db.Query(PersonComment)
  comments.ancestor(person_key)
  comments.filter('verified = ', True)
  comments.order('-added')
  comments.fetch(PAGE_SIZE_COMMENTS+1, (page)*PAGE_SIZE_COMMENTS)
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fetch` returns a result set; `comments` is still a Query object. You can do this:

`comments = comments.fetch(PAGE_SIZE_COMMENTS+1, (page)*PAGE_SIZE_COMMENTS)`

Or call your query object something else to avoid confusion.

As an aside, using fetch with an offset for pagination is really inefficient. Consider using [query cursors](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors).

Comment: Thanks, Drew. Does fetch really read all records and returns just what I've requested (compared to the cursor)? Why should I use cursor?

Comment: @LA_ Get rid of query with offset and use cursors as suggested. Queries with offset are inefficient and, billing wise, cost a lot of Datastore reads.